# Comparing block versus non-block Krylov methods for handling multiple right-hand-sides

Tags: linear-solver, krylov-method, gmres

Suppose I wish to solve a linear system $AX=B$ iteratively where $A$ is an $m\times m$ matrix and $X,B$ are $m \times s $ matrices (not single vectors). Instead of solving $s$ independent systems I'm exploring ways to solve them simultaneously so that matrix-vector products may better use caching (i.e. calculating $AX$ should require only a single read of $A$ whereas $Ax_1,\ldots,Ax_s$ would require $s$ reads of $A$.)

One approach would be simply to feed this as a linear system of size $ms$ into e.g. GMRES.

I have seen other so-called Block-GMRES algorithms which use instead a block-Arnoldi factorization.

The block-GMRES approaches appear a little more complex to implement and it's not clear if the added complexity is worthwhile.

Is it known whether block-GMRES outperforms non-block-GMRES in terms of:

1. memory required to achieve solution
2. number of matrix-matrix products $AX$ required to compute solution
3. Improved communication profile (maybe block-GMRES requires fewer synchronization points? or can pipeline better?)

Comment: What do you mean with "feed this as a linear system of size $ms$ into e.g. GMRES"? Vanilla GMRES can only handle systems with one right-hand side vector. Do you mean solving $s$ linear systems independently with it?

Comment: The operator defined by $X \rightarrow AX$ is linear so you can pass that into GMRES. but where $A$ has shape $m \times m$ the operator $X \rightarrow AX$ has shape $ms \times ms$.

Comment: I clarified the question: I'm really after an iterative method that can cache reads of the matrix $A$ by turning multiple matrix-vector products into a single matrix-matrix product.

Comment: Another issue is the cost of orthogonalization with block-GMRES. Yes, you'll be able to use BLAS level-3 operations rather than level-2, but it is unclear if this will be beneficial. If you're in a setting where parallel computing is available, $s$ repetitions of GMRES for each RHS may outperform block-GMRES.

Comment: If you try to input multiple right-hand sides into regular GMRES, likely you will encounter data structure issues. Another issue is with the Arnoldi process. The standard forms of Householder, Gram-Schmidt, or any other orthogonalization procedures are not designed to handle multiple vectors at once. Block-GMRES methods are designed around these restrictions and you should use them over the regular one if $s$ is large (but large depends on the available amount of memory, memory lane bandwidth and CPU cache sizes, My guess is $s>5$ and $m>1,000,000$ would be the boundary on modern machines.)

Comment: Just a comment, not an answer - block Krylov methods work fairly well in settings where the RHS are related since their Krylov spaces may share information. For example, scattering problems often involve lots of plane wave forcing functions, and selecting groups of plane waves clustered in the angular dimension can lead to improved performance over vanilla GMRES. Of course, one should select the minimum number of RHS for such a problem, which probably limits the benefit of block Krylov methods.